# AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'fit'

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to fit a distribution to a vector of data, but I am getting this error, anyone knows how to solve?

I am using the scipy example: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fit.html

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'fit'
```

Comment: did you first do `from scipy import stats`?

Comment: I suspect your version of SciPy is too old. Which version of SciPy do you have installed? If you don't know, you can check by running the Python code `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.